# Angular "An asset cannot be written to a location outside of the output path" after update to v16

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I was trying to update an Angular app to Angular 16 (from Angular 15), but I get the following error after the update process when running `npm run start`:
`An unhandled exception occurred: An asset cannot be written to a location outside of the output path.`

A more detailed error description is:

```
C:\**redacted for confidentiality**\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\util\reportUnhandledError.js:13
            throw err;
            ^

Error: An asset cannot be written to a location outside of the output path.
    at C:\***redacted for confidentiality***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\normalize-asset-patterns.js:87:19
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeAssetPatterns (C:\***redacted for confidentiality***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\normalize-asset-patterns.js:50:26)
    at normalizeBrowserSchema (C:\**redacted for confidentiality**\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\normalize-builder-schema.js:22:71)
    at generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (C:\***redacted for confidentiality***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:116:66)
    at async generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (C:\***redacted for confidentiality***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:67:20)
    at async setup (C:\***redacted for confidentiality***\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\builders\dev-server\webpack-server.js:96:34)

Node.js v18.17.1
```

NodeJS 18.17.1
Windows 10

I updated the app from Angular 15 to Angular 16 (`npm run ng update`). Everything went fine, I have ran `npm install` after and when running the project for test I got this error.

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Comment: Yes...the problem came from angular.json. Some paths were given with `./..` and I changed them to `./`. The run command and build command works (yayy...no Sonar issues), but when it creates the `dist` folder after building, it can not run because some folders are created wrongfully (can be fixed manually, but if there's an automated script on the cloud, it breaks)